# appium long press and than move element(drag and drop) is not working

Tags: java, appium, appium-ios

I have a scenario to test an IOS app like this:

> 1. long press on an element.
> 2. move that element to desired location.

I am using the following code:

```
TouchAction action = new TouchAction(driver)
action.long_press(element1).move_to(element2).wait(500).release().perform()
```

but its not working for me. Need any good suggestion.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

i was in trouble also about this. But i solved this like below:

```
TouchAction action = new TouchAction(driver);
action.longPress(elem1).waitAction(3000).moveTo(elem2).perform().release();
```

`waitAction` will wait to complete `longPress` action and then `moveTo` action will perform.

Comment: Now, TouchAction is deprecated. What else I can work with? Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2):

I found none of the longPress() combinations to work, so I got to this variant where you force it to perform the press and then move. Tested on Android and iOS, didn't seem to work for UWP

```
new TouchAction(driver)
    .press(PointOption.point(256, 1115))
    .waitAction(WaitOptions.waitOptions(Duration.ofMillis(2000)))
    .perform()
    .moveTo(PointOption.point(256, 600))
    .release()
    .perform();
```

Comment: press() is for scroll, longPress() is for drag

Comment: The longPress() didn't work for me. Tried the top voted answer and nothing. I had a custom view that I had drawn myself on a canvas. Don't know if that had anything to do with it, but this is the only solution that worked for me Android and iOS

Answer (score 2):

```
//You need to import following 
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import io.appium.java_client.TouchAction;
import io.appium.java_client.touch.LongPressOptions;
import io.appium.java_client.touch.offset.ElementOption;

//first for the intial location to be long pressed
WebElement first= driver.findElementByXPath("//*[@content-desc='15']");

//second location on which you need to move to
WebElement second= driver.findElementByXPath("//*[@content-desc='45']");

TouchAction action = new TouchAction(driver);

//performing the long press
action.longPress(new LongPressOptions().withElement(new 
                       ElementOption().withElement(first))).perform();

//performing the move to touch operation
action.moveTo(new ElementOption().withElement(second)).perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

> if U have references of elements already then you'll do like this:

```
TouchAction action = new TouchAction(driver);
        action.longPress(new ElementOption().withElement(first))
                .waitAction(WaitOptions.waitOptions(Duration.ofMillis(3000)))
                .moveTo(new ElementOption().withElement(last))
                .release()
                .perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

Following solution works for me on **iOS with python**:

> **TouchAction(context.driver).long_press(source_element).move_to(destination_element).release().perform()**

Answer (score 0):

This has worked for me (tried on Android):

```java
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.clickAndHold(element1).pause(2000).moveToElement(element2).perform();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
action.press(Element1).moveTo(Element2).release().perform();
```